# angular check column in matCellDef loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

How do we check a column in an ng for loop in angular ? for example I dont wanna apply the logic below which is   {{element[p.key] != null ? '$' : ''}} to column 1  or execept column 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6dWU.png)

#html code

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="bovDemos" class="mat-elevation-z0">
                    <ng-container  *ngFor="let p of marketDemographicsTableLabel; last as l" matColumnDef="{{p.key}}">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="fs-12px">{{p.label}}</th>
                      <ng-container >
                        <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i"
                        [ngClass]="{'border-none': i === bovDemos.length - 1}" class="fs-12px">
                        {{element[p.key] != null ? '$' : ''}}{{(element[p.key]) ? (element[p.key] | number): '-'}}</td>
                      </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableMarketDemographicsHeaders"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableMarketDemographicsHeaders;" class="cursor-default">
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

Comment: I don't wanna apply the $ sign and the pipe number to any data that is in column 1 , or the column of the Demos basd on the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set "index as i", so you can use "i" to detect first td.

```
<span *ngIf="i===0">
   ..this is first column
 </span>
<span *ngIf="i!==0">
{{element[p.key] != null ? '$' : ''}}{{(element[p.key]) ? (element[p.key] | number): '-'}}
</span>
```